# Watir/Selenium - Why can I not connect to any browser?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying for the first time to use Watir for automated browser-based testing. For all browsers I'm interested in testing with (Firefox, Chrome), I encounter timeout errors trying to connect.

Here's what I'm trying, with the errors I get in comments:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff

# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
# unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:56602
```

System/environment details:

- Ubuntu desktop 11.04
- Apache2 running on same host but only listening to port 80
- gem selenium-webdriver version is 2.17.0
- ruby version is 1.8.7

I'm guessing I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but I don't know enough to know where to start investigating what may be wrong. All I am aware of is that nothing is running on the ports that Selenium is trying to connect to.

What is needed for this to work?

Comment: Did you follow my instructions on how to install Ruby and Watir on Ubuntu? https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md

Comment: Yes, I followed those exact instructions

Comment: What version of firefox?   For chromedriver, see the selenium chromedriver wiki which has some detailed info on setting this stuff up for a linux system.  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: Have you considered perhaps using something like VirtualBox or VMWare to create a windows VM and run your tests there?   If you believe statcounter, windows as a platform is something around 94% of the web userbase, so it would get you running the same versions of the browsers as most of your users are likely to be using, and you could also test on IE which is still the most used browser at just under 40% see: http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-201012-201112.  More importantly, in my experience webdriver is pretty easy to get working on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the headless gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'

Headless.ly do
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, on RedHat based systems, the Xvfb binary is called "Xvfb". Make a link called "xvfb" so that the headless gem finds it.

`$ ln -s  /usr/bin/Xvfb /usr/local/bin/xvfb`